# JavaFX's TreeTableView has poor node expansion performance

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, openjfx

We migrated from Swing to JavaFX, and also exchanged a custom Swing TreeTableView control with JavaFX's [`TreeTableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html).

Yet, we experience a noticeable delay when expanding a node.

[image]

Looking at this issue with VisualVM, we found out that most time is spent in `Parent.scenesChanged()` and `CssStyleHelper.createStyleHelper()`. Yet, we were not able to derive a solution for fast expanding from this.

**Has anybody else experienced such problems with JavaFX's `TreeTableView`?**

The amount of nodes should not be the reason, there are some few hundred nodes on the first level (i.e., below the root), and each of this nodes has about 20 children.

Additional info: We are running Ubuntu, with openjfx version (8u60-b27-4).

Comment: I have the same experiences if I have a lot of data in  the `TreeTableView` I thought the delay is caused by the relative complex check in the `updateItem` method, so I let it as it is, but i am not sure if this is the problem, it is just an assumption from my side.I would be very glad if anyone can give us an answer for this problem.

Comment: @Sunflame We don't do complex things in `updateItem`, and also experience similar performance problems (with the same hot spot methods) when using JavaFX charts with many data points.

Comment: Weniger I have just checked it, once with 3 colums and 2 children of the `TreeItem` and it expands/collapses smoothly(107 `updateItem` calls), I don't see any delay, but If I test the same view(same settings) with 33 columns and 3 children for a `TreeItem` when I expand it, or collapse it I can observe the delay(1503 `updateItem` calls). So that's why I thought it depends on the `updateItem` method calls and its checks operations make the delay. 107 vs 1503 I think it is a reasonable difference.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve] which replicates the performance issue?  It may help in motivating somebody to help analyze the issue.

Comment: Possibly this relates to this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8088253 ?